# Rearranging a pair of arrays with respect to a sorted third array made from the previous two

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Suppose I have 3 arrays.

`arr1 = {96, 100, 104, 108}`

`arr2 = {8, 4, 4, 16}`

Now I create a third array in which I will store elements = `arr1[i]/arr2[i]`

Therefore `arr3 = {12, 25, 26, 9}`

Now I want to sort `arr3`. But also sort `arr1` and `arr2` in the same order.

Like now `arr3 = {9, 12, 25, 26}` I also want to sort `arr1` and `arr2` by the same order meaning

`arr1 = {108, 96, 100, 104} arr2 = {16, 8, 4, 4}`

So for `arr3[2] = 26` I can print/use `arr1[2] = 96 && arr2[2] = 8`.

I want to be able to access the element of `arr1` and `arr2` by `arr3`.

Comment: Create a structure which will have three elements (arr1[i],arr2[i],arr3[i]). make an array of structures and sort them based on third element. Refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-sorting-in-c/ for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't sort the array, sort the indexes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr1[] = {96, 100, 104, 108};
int arr2[] = {8, 4, 4, 16};
int arr3[] = {12, 25, 26, 9};

int delta(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return arr3[*aa] - arr3[*bb];
}

int main(void) {
    int indexes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    qsort(indexes, 4, sizeof (int), delta);

    printf("arr1:");
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        printf(" %d", arr1[indexes[k]]);
    }
    printf("\narr2:");
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        printf(" %d", arr2[indexes[k]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

<sub>Sorry for the globals.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all?) sorting will use swapping of elements. When you sort `arr3` and swap elements of it, just swap the corresponding elements of the other arrays as well.

So when you swap e.g. `arr3[i]` with `arr3[j]`, then also swap `arr1[i]` with `arr1[j]` and `arr2[i]` with `arr2[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

First you define a data structure to hold the values:

```
typedef struct {
    int dividend, divisor, result;
} intTuple;
```

Then you define a sorting function for C's `qsort`

```
int compare(const intTuple *e1, const intTuple *e2){
    return (e1->result > e2->result)? 1 : 0;
}
```

Then you initialize the data, perform the division and call the `qsort`:

```
int main() {
    intTuple tuples[4] = { {96, 8}, {100, 4}, {104, 8}, {108, 16} };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tuples[i].result = tuples[i].dividend / tuples[i].divisor;
    }
    qsort(tuples, 4, sizeof(intTuple), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d ", tuples[i].dividend);
    }
}
```

Test it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkIknzqqX).

Comment: How to see compilation warnings and errors on onlinegdb? You should get used to making your compiler emit warnings as in [ideone](https://ideone.com/9ti6Hr).

Comment: Good question! I don't know. I use Visual studio most of the time, but `qsort` didn't work in it, hence why I resorted to this online tool. There was a "share" option, so I thought I might as well use that.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// created a structure containing three elements
struct node
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} arr[3];

// comparator function which is used to sort structure based on its one property 'c' value
bool compareTwoStudents(node aa, node bb) 
{ 
    return (aa.c < bb.c); 
} 

int main() {
    
    arr[0].a=96;
    arr[1].a=100;
    arr[2].a=108;
    
    arr[0].b=8;
    arr[1].b=4;
    arr[2].b=16;
    
    arr[0].c=12;
    arr[1].c=25;
    arr[2].c=9;
    
    // sort function of c++, takes third argument as the custom comparator function
    sort(arr, arr+3, compareTwoStudents); 
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i].a<<" "<<arr[i].b<<" "<<arr[i].c<<"\n";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Why `C++` answer for `C` question?